# Golang index an array of strings

Tags: go

Hi I have a string that says this.

```
         "Style: Saison
      
          ABV: 7.7
      
      
       IBU: 20"
```

I try to split it into an array so that I can get **Saison**

Here is how I convert to array.

```
    style :=strings.Split(style, "Style:")
```

When I do
`style[0]`

It doesn't index Saison. I also tried style[1] and style[2] and nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Style = []string so it is a list of strings right?

Comment: Yes, the split result is a `[]string`, but I don't understand why you think you're going to get `Saison`. Trying printing everything and see what exactly you're working with.

Comment: style[0] try that

Comment: @jimB Do you understand what I am asking, read my question again please. I am trying to get Saison.

Comment: @MattQuaine yes, but how would splittng on `Style:` and getting the 0th element accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [strings.**FieldsFunc**](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#FieldsFunc):

> FieldsFunc splits the string s at each run of Unicode code points c
> satisfying f(c) and returns an array of slices of s. If all code
> points in s satisfy f(c) or the string is empty, an empty slice is
> returned.
>
> FieldsFunc makes no guarantees about the order in which it calls f(c)
> and assumes that f always returns the same value for a given c.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    str := `Style: Saison Drink

ABV: 7.7

IBU: 20`
    f := func(c rune) bool {
        return c == ':' || c == '\n'
    }

    strFields := strings.FieldsFunc(str, f)
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", strFields)

    styleValue := strings.TrimSpace(strFields[1])
    fmt.Println(styleValue)

    abvValue, err := strconv.ParseFloat(strings.TrimSpace(strFields[3]), 32)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error parsing float!")
    }
    fmt.Printf("%.2f\n", abvValue)

    ibuValue, err := strconv.ParseInt(strings.TrimSpace(strFields[5]), 10, 32)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error parsing int!")
    }
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", ibuValue)
}
```

**Output:**

```
["Style" " Saison Drink" "ABV" " 7.7" "IBU" " 20"]
Saison Drink
7.70
20
```

---

Comment: Thank you very much! this is good but what there was a space between the words. Like "Saison Drink"?

Comment: Hmm, ok will update the answer for that new use case

Comment: but what if I wanted to get 7.7? strFields[2] doesn't work

Comment: Updated answer :)